# Is $p\neq 0$, then there are $x_+, x_- \in \mathbb{C}$ with $x_\pm ^2=p$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Is $p\neq 0$, then there are $x_+, x_- \in \mathbb{C}$ with $x_\pm ^2=p$.

My proof:

The proof for $p>0$ is trivial, since $\mathbb{R}\subset \mathbb{C}$ and it's true $\forall p\in \mathbb{R}$.

The proof for $p<0$:  Since $i:=\sqrt{-1}$  and $p$ would be a multiple of $\sqrt{-1}$ since $\sqrt{p}$ with $p>0$ can be rewritten als $\sqrt{-1\cdot (-p)}=\sqrt{-1}\cdot \sqrt{-p}$

Comment: is it assumed $p\in\Bbb R$ ?

Comment: If $p \in \mathbb{C} $, then look at the equation $ t^2 - p =0$, from the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra, we have two solutions to this.

Comment: $p\in \mathbb{C}$

Comment: P-addict, is there another way to prove it?

Comment: For $p > 0$, we have $(\sqrt p)^2 = p$ and $(-\sqrt p)^2 = p$. For $p < 0$ we have $(i\sqrt{|p|})^2  = i^2(\sqrt{|p|})^2 = -1|p| = p$ and $(-i\sqrt{|p|})^2 = (-1)^2i^2(\sqrt{|p|})^2 = (1)(-1)(|p|) = p$. Of course, here it is assumed that $p$ is real, but that is not necessary. This is also true when $p$ is allowed to be complex.

Comment: But why is also true when $p$ is allowed to be complex